# Stream closed: writeParagraphVectors for large file deeplearning4j

Tags: java, training-data, deeplearning4j, doc2vec, bigdata

I am trying to train Doc2Vec model using the following code:

```
String modelPath = "input_data.csv";
File file = new File(modelPath);
SentenceIterator iter = new BasicLineIterator(file);

AbstractCache<VocabWord> cache = new AbstractCache<>();

TokenizerFactory t = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();
t.setTokenPreProcessor(new CommonPreprocessor());

LabelsSource source = new LabelsSource("DOC_");

ParagraphVectors vec = new ParagraphVectors.Builder()
    .minWordFrequency(1)
    .iterations(5)
    .epochs(1)
    .layerSize(100)
    .learningRate(0.025)
    .labelsSource(source)
    .windowSize(5)
    .iterate(iter)
    .trainWordVectors(false)
    .vocabCache(cache)
    .tokenizerFactory(t)
    .sampling(0)
    .workers(4)
    .build();

vec.fit();
File tempFile = new File("trained_model.zip");
WordVectorSerializer.writeParagraphVectors(vec, tempFile);
```

- This code works for small input file
- When I try to execute this code on large file (18GB), I am getting the following error

  ```
  .........
  o.d.m.s.SequenceVectors - Time spent on training: 5667912 ms
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
  at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.writeParagraphVectors(WordVectorSerializer.java:477)
  at org.deeplearning4j.examples.nlp.paragraphvectors.ParagraphVectorsTextExample.main(ParagraphVectorsTextExample.java:73)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
  at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.writeWordVectors(WordVectorSerializer.java:393)
  at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.writeParagraphVectors(WordVectorSerializer.java:687)
  at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.writeParagraphVectors(WordVectorSerializer.java:475)
  ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
  at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
  at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
  at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
  at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.writeWordVectors(WordVectorSerializer.java:392)
  ... 3 more
  ```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Do you see a partially-written file with the `trained_model.zip` filename, and if so how large is it? To what sort of filesystem are you writing?

Comment: If I train on small file it has some size. 
If I train on large file it has a size of 0kb. I am working on linux file system

Comment: Hmm, so it fails before writing a single byte, but does create the file. Is there a possibility your OS/filesystem doesn't support files larger than 2GB or 4GB? Are you making both the small and large tests at the exact same path  as the same user? If you try progressively-larger models, is there a sharp consistent threshold size where it switches from successful to unsuccessful?

Comment: I am having somewhat similar problem - but it's different in the sense that it just takes lot of time to write the file, and after reaching some size(around 13 GB), program just hangs there. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I got it working. ONly thing is it takes lot of time and memory to write file